# "onchange = this.form.submit()" isn't working in html(ejs)

Tags: javascript, html, ejs, onchange

I am not getting the data when I am submitting/posting using onchange="this.form.submit()" in ejs(embedded javascript) file when I have logged the data I should get something in response but I am not getting anything
heres the code:

```
<% newListItems.forEach(function(items){ %>

      <form action="/delete" method="POST">

        <div class="item">
          <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%= items._id %>" onchange=" this.form.submit(); ">
          <p><%=  items.name  %></p>
        </div>

      </form>
<% }) %>
```

please help.

Comment: Only checked boxes get sent to the server. When you uncheck the box, it will submit an empty form.

Comment: yeah but whenever I am checking the box i should get something on my delete post route. But when I am logging it, it is showing undefined.

Comment: IDs should be unique, you shouldn't have the same `id="checkbox"` for every item. Either remove the ID (you're probably not using it) or add some unique value to it each time through the loop.

Comment: Are you sure there's an`_id` property in `items`?

Comment: Do you see the value when you examine the checkbox in DevTools?

Comment: yes there is _id property. I am using mongoosejs to delete this data when ever I checked on this particular item.

Comment: Does the Network tab of DevTools show `checkbox=ID` in the POST data?

Comment: No the network tab is empty

Comment: shouldn't it be `onchange="this.closest('form').submit();"` ?

Comment: I suggest putting it in a hidden input rather than using the checkbox value.

Comment: @Kinglish Not necessary. All inputs in a form have a `form` property that refers to the containing form. `closest()` is a very recent addition.

Comment: @Kinglish I tried your method It is not working either, it is giving the same response.

Comment: Thank you all, my problem has been resolved after debugging for a time and it was some error in my route app, I was using some function but didn't require the particular module for it.
I appreciate all of your help until this.